# Как конвертировать файлы авторизации TelegramDesktop в telegram-cli?

Tags: telegram

При авторизации через Telegram Desktop создается папка tdata, которая содержит набор файлов для поддержания аутентификации при заходе в приложение.

Мне необходимо перенести эти файлы в telegram-cli. Проблема в том, что telegram-cli требуются один единственный файл auth в директории с .telegram-cli
Его можно получить только авторизовавшись в telegram-cli через telegram-desktop введя код из сообщения.
Возможно ли каким то образом получить нужный файл auth для авторизации в telegram-cli из набора файлов telegram-desktop? Штудирую исходный код, но ничего не выходит. Может кто сможет подсказать?